# Low voltage on 300V H-Bridge

Tags: h-bridge

I'm trying to make a 300V H Bridge for an electrostimulator. The circuitry is as posted here, using MOSFET P20NM60GP:

[image: circuit]

When I tested it with low voltage supply (just for the sake of safe testing), and a 15 Watts 1kOhm resistor I get the output waveform I desire, that is:

[image: low voltage]

However, when I try to change the supply voltage to 300V (galvanically isolated, safety first!), with the same 15Watts, 1kOhm resistor I get this output:

[image]

The probe is set to x10, corresponding with the x10 oscilloscope, so those are real 500mV per division. The frequency and waveform are fine, it's just that the voltage output is hyper low- was expecting to get about 300V peak.

Any ideas as to why is this H Bridge misbehaving on High voltage? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What makes you think a 15W 1KOhm resistor can withstand 300V across it? Even at 50%? Your scope is also measuring 300 but wrong magnitude.

Comment: In what way was the 300 volt supply galvanically isolated - it needs to share the same ground connection as your H-bridge. Try it with a much higher resistance load first so that it doesn't melt-down.

Comment: Yikes! Thanks for noticing that! I forgot to change the resistor! I planned to later add a current source limiting current to 100mA, and that's why I used had that resistance; Yes, I'm definitely changing it to 2MOhm for testing, and I also have everything on the same ground connection (learned from my mistake), but I still can't understand the reason why I have such a low voltage on the output!

@DKNguyen, when you say "Your scope is also measuring 300 but wrong magnitude" what do you mean? That I'm getting 300, but mV instead of V?

Comment: @EmiIbañez I'm just saying it's really suspicious that you are measuring the correct numerical value but the wrong order of magnitude. Normally this is because your probe and oscilloscope settings don't match but we've already established that you couldn't possibly be putting 300V across that resistor it else it would have already blown up.